# Log files not showing access to a jpeg, but the access happened

Tags: apache, logging, grep, ubuntu-14.04, access-log

I put a jpeg on a webpage, now I want to see who did access it. I know that at least 40 people must have seen it according to a counter.
I looked through /var/www/vhosts with `grep jpeg.jpg -r /var/www/vhosts`yet I could only find a few accesses by my own ip.

Where do I find the logs that show who accessed the jpg?

Comment: I suspect it might be important to mention which web server you use... apache, nginx, lighttpd. Further, Stack Overflow is probably not the correct website as it is for programming questions only - try SuperUser.

Comment: Added apache....